# How to get the Below output with the given Input in Console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I have an input as below in a excel. Consider the space between the values as next cell value.
[Actual Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCuKg.png)

My Output should be,

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct0Re.png)

The columns and rows are not fixed. Now i want to get the expected output as given. Please help me to achieve this.

I have tried with Loop,
I have got the output as,
[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaUen.png)

Here is the code that I have used to print the record.

```
    for(int Currow = 0 ; Currow <dt.rows.count; curRow++)

{
for(int CurCol = 0 ; CurCol<dt.Columns.count; CurCol ++)
{
if(dt.Rows[Currow][CurCol].ToString().Trim() != "")
   {
   string Modified Value = dt.Rows[Currow][CurCol].ToString().Trim();
   string NewValue = ModifiedValue.Replace("PersonName_","");
   Console.WriteLine(NewValue + " | ");
   }
}
if(currow    %    2 == 1)
    {
if(!dt.Rows[Currow][CurCol].ToString().Contains != "PersonName_"))
     {
Console.WriteLine();
     }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGF23.png)

Actual result:
[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VynNB.png)

Comment: I think the question is clear now.

Comment: Please let me know why the question has been marked as negative in comment box?

Comment: use String.Format